# my car cuts off while driving

Tags: dodge, neon

While I Am driving my car will just cut off and it takes a while to crank up then at Times it cut off start up then cut right back off again and again I don't know wats wrong

Comment: Can you add some more information? Like the year, engine, mileage of your Neon? Also, how long have you been driving when the car shuts off? Is it completely random (can happen when warmed up or cold)? Give us something to go on and we can surely lead you in the right direction.

Comment: First thing to look at would be fault codes.  You should be able to get them checked at your local parts store.  If its old enough you might be able to turn the key on-off-on-off-on and have it blink the codes to you.  Sounds like a fuel pump.  When it shuts down, and you try to restart it, listen for the fuel pump hum.  The previous generation cars (k-cars) had an issue with the Hall Effect Pickup under the distributor that would give similar results.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem some years ago and it turned out to be a blocked breather on the fuel tank.

Next time it happens to you, provided you are somewhere that it's safe to do this, jump out of the car and pull the fuel filler cap off and listen around the neck of the fuel tank of a whooshing noise, as though air is being sucked into the tank.

If this is the case then the car should start up again fairly easily and repair is a case of clearing the tanks breather hose.

Alternatively the problem could be a wiring fault or issue with a fuel pump relay.